# Как добавить новые элементы в коллекцию без цикла?

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация, коллекции, plsql

Есть тестовая таблица. И есть прототип функции, которая должна дополнять коллекцию новыми элементами из различных таблиц.

```sql
create table tab (grp, nam, val) as
    select 'grp'||(mod (rownum, 3)+1), 'name'||rownum, 'value'||rownum
    from dual connect by level<=9
/
create or replace function addList (l tblt, grp varchar2) return tblt as
    cursor cur (grp varchar2) is
        select objt (grp, nam, val)
        from tab where grp = cur.grp;
    ret tblt := l;
    tmp tblt; 
begin 
    open cur (grp); 
    fetch cur bulk collect into tmp;
    for i in 1..tmp.count loop 
        ret.extend; 
        ret(ret.last) := tmp(i);
    end loop;    
    return ret;
end;
/
```

После получения новых записей в `fetch`, добавляю их к существующей колекции в цикле `for-loop`. Думаю, что есть более лаконичный способ без цикла.

Как можно добавить новые записи к существующей колекции без цикла?

В текущем виде, функция работает и даёт желаемый результат:

```sql
var rc refcursor
declare
    tbl tblt := tblt (objt ('grp0', 'name0', 'value0'));
begin 
    tbl := addList (tbl, 'grp2');
    open :rc for select * from table (tbl);
end;
/
```

```
+------+-------+--------+
| GRP  | NAME  | VALUE  |
+------+-------+--------+
| grp0 | name0 | value0 |
| grp2 | name1 | value1 |
| grp2 | name4 | value4 |
| grp2 | name7 | value7 |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62993791

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое, добавить новые записи PL/SQL оператором [MULTISET UNION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/operations-on-collection-data-types.html#GUID-4861552D-787F-457A-BAFF-D44390FB77ED):

```
create or replace function addList2 (old tblt, grp varchar2) return tblt as
    cursor cur (grp varchar2) is
        select objt (grp, nam, val)
        from tab where grp = cur.grp
        order by grp, nam;
    new tblt;
begin 
    open cur (grp); 
    fetch cur bulk collect into new;
    return (old multiset union all new);
end;
/
```

Также можно сразу объединить новые элементы с существующей колекцией добавив её в SQL запросе оператором объединения таблиц [UNION ALL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE). Так будет возможность отсортировать результирующую коллекцию:

```
create or replace function addList1 (old tblt, grp varchar2) return tblt as
    cursor cur (old tblt, grp varchar2) is 
        select objt (grp, nam, val) from (
        select grp, nam, val
        from tab where grp = cur.grp
        union all
        select * from table (old) s
        ) order by grp, nam;
    ret tblt;
begin 
    open cur (old, grp); 
    fetch cur bulk collect into ret;
    close cur; 
    return ret;
end;
/
```

Оба способа дадут желемый результат:

```
declare
    tbl tblt := tblt (objt ('grp0', 'name0', 'value0'));
begin 
    tbl := addList1 (tbl, 'grp1');
    tbl := addList2 (tbl, 'grp2');
    open :rc for select * from table (tbl);
end;
/

GRP  NAME             VALUE           
---- ---------------- ----------------
grp0 name0            value0          
grp1 name3            value3          
grp1 name6            value6          
grp1 name9            value9          
grp2 name1            value1          
grp2 name4            value4          
grp2 name7            value7
```